# XPATH Conformance

Tags: xslt, xpath, standards-compliance

I have an XPath engine implementation that needs to be tested.

Is there a set of standard conformance tests that we can apply to validate that conforms to the XPath specification (in relation to XSLT).

What would be perfect would be XML documents XPath expression and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [W3C XQuery test suite](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/test-suite/) that [at least one person](http://intellectualcramps.blogspot.com/2009/06/w3c-xpath-20-test-suite-implemented.html) has used to test against XPath.